# Export actual functions for different routes in different files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Currently my routes file is setup like this:

```
    const logoutHelper = function (request, response) {
        if (request.session) {
            console.log("User '" + request.session.username + "' logged out.");
            request.session.destroy(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                } else {
                    return response.redirect('/');
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Logout user and delete the session object
    app.get('/logout', logoutHelper);
```

How can I move the logoutHelper functions to another file in the same directory? I want to split the post and get routes into different files because my original routes.js grew too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your new file:

```
const logoutHelper = function (request, response) {
    if (request.session) {
        console.log("User '" + request.session.username + "' logged out.");
        request.session.destroy(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            } else {
                return response.redirect('/');
            }
        });
    }
}

module.exports = {
    logoutHelper: logoutHelper
};
```

In your route file:

```
const Helpers = require('<helper file>');

// Logout user and delete the session object
app.get('/logout', Helpers.logoutHelper);
```

Something else to note, you are using `next` but don't have it defined in your callback function. You probably need to add it as the third parameter of the logoutHelper function.

Also I'm assuming you're not using es6-you can probably clean up that export object if you are.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.